# Flutter overflow cutoff

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a card in Flutter, I want to cutoff the overflowing text but I cant seem to get it working.

[image]

```
return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(task.tag + " " + task.tagomschrijving, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, 
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children:[
                      Text("Task: " + task.taakomschrijving, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                      Text("Lubricant: " + task.smeermiddel),
                      if(task.aantalsmeerpunten != 0) Text("Quantity: " + task.aantalsmeerpunten.toString() + " x " + task.hoeveelheid.toString() + " " + task.eenheid),
                      if(task.aantalsmeerpunten == 0) Text(""),
                    ]
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the second `Column` Widget with `Flexible` widget.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also found it myself. I modified my question because the layout wasn't as beautiful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I added the expanded widget at the Text level and not at column level. It is working now

Comment: For Future =>  If you face it again then wrape it in padding also you can use container and inside container you can use padding or you can you height and width of container of also expended wisget and also flexible :-)

Comment: For this question  (cutoff) I don’t have the answer yet. Do you know it?

Comment: Wrape text in padding then give padding : EdgeInsets.only(right:5.0),

Comment: It worked with 
                  Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children:[
                        Text("Task: " + task.taakomschrijving, maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),